# Tabulator checkbox multiple selection

Tags: tabulator

In tabulator I used a checkbox for select all and deselect all ,
for checkbox checked and unchecked i used a following code,
**For checked**

```
$('input[name = custmisedtab]').prop('checked', true);
```

**For Unchecked**

```
$('input[name = custmisedtab]').prop('checked', false);
```

when I was checked it will checked a only that records that are shown in screen not all which is shown after scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

With Tabulator, you should not be modifying the DOM directly - instead, update the data object of the table.  You should have a column with a custom formatter to display a checkbox, checked based on the columns value.  To update their state, call `table.updateData()` or `table.updateRow()` for all the rows.

Your current code doesn't update the checkboxes beyond the scrollbar because of Tabulator's virtualization.  When you try to set the checkbox states, the rows beyond the scrollbar aren't actually part of the DOM yet, and thus aren't available to jQuery to update.